# Using SharePoint 2013 to Crawl SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2010, 2013, search, sharepoint-server, crawl

I've having a bit of trouble with SharePoint 2013 search. I'm trying to use it to crawl a SharePoint 2007 site. What I've done is I've set up a content source to that site, created a crawl rule with the following:

- Include items in this path

  - Crawl complex URLs (URLs that contain a question mark - ?)
  - Crawl SharePoint content as http pages

I've also specified that the rule use the SharePoint 2007 crawl account to crawl the SharePoint 2007 site. I even verified that the crawl would crawl the site by testing a URL on the rules page and sure enough it says:

"The url will be crawled because it matches the rule ("http://[sitename]/*") marked with a *."

However, when I actually run the crawl it just crawl the root site http://[sitename] and stops. The crawl log has zero errors and one success. What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do the protocols for the URLs on your content source look like?

Comment: It's just standard HTTP. Nothing very fancy.

Comment: Use SPS3 http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2007/03/19/crawling-sharepoint-sites-using-the-sps3-protocol-handler.aspx

Comment: If it matters our SP2013 Central Administration is running HTTPS.

Comment: Using SPS3 only crawls the profiles, according to the crawl log, and doesn't seem to crawl the site. The rules and content source are configured the same in SP2013 as they are in SP2007 and the crawl works flawlessly in the SP2007 farm.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have similar requirements and I wonder what's the best solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

Does your crawl account have access to the 2007 site?

If you are still struggling you can watch the requests by using Fiddler as a proxy for the crawl process. Then you can kick off the crawl and watch the requests and the response from the 2007 server.

Comment: My SP2013 crawl account doesn't have any specific permissions to the SP2007 site. I haven't given it any explicit permissions since I set the SP2013 crawl rule to use the SP2007 crawl account. I assumed that would be enough. Is that not the case? I'll take a look at Fiddler and see what I can come up with. I've only used that tool to view traffic generated by the browser and I'm not sure how to monitor something like a crawl that's not running in a browser using Fiddler so there'll be some playing around on my end.

Comment: I think I found my answer on how to use Fiddler: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2012/01/04/troubleshooting-sharepoint-search-crawl/. I'll read your blog post, Matt, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: No dice, unfortunately. First, thanks for the tip. Running the crawl through the Fiddler proxy is really neat. I would never have thought of doing something like that. Anyways, it looks like the crawl is hitting the first page, /Document.aspx, and then it just stops. I tried this with both the SP2007 and SP2013 crawl accounts and both yielded the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can crawl the data. if u cannot able to use out of box connector then try to use RESTAPI. you will definitely able to crawl the datas.